# How to find Excel labeled Cell

Tags: excel, com, vba

This is what I have:

1) an Excel sheet where cells are labeled (named **Edit:** in the "Name box").

2) a COM connection to the Excel sheet.

Now, how can I retrieve the value of the cell using the label of the cell?

Example:

```
mySheet.Cells(1,5).TEXT
```

Would yield the value of the cell R1C5. However, I cannot find any method on how to retrieve the value using a label (which is possible in the older DDE), that is I miss something like

```
mySheet.Cells("theNameOfTheCell").TEXT
```

Is there a better guide than this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194567(v=office.14).aspx

(I work from OpenEdge Progress 11.5, **Edit:** and Excel 2010 )

Any ideas??

Comment: Found [this](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2012.2/CLR4.0/HTML/ExcelEngine_Accessing_Cells_and_Cell_Regions_by_Name.html#_Ref317855283), but it does not seem to help either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `Range` property to use the named range:

`mySheet.Range("cellName").Text`

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it did not work for me. Do you have an other suggestion? Btw I use Excel 2010.

Comment: Text property will try to do a text with all the range, which is usually a matrix of cells. May be that is not what you expect.
You could try to access individual cells, using coordinates relative to the range. if you know there is only one cell, then try
`range := mySheet.Range("cellName")
range.Cells(1, 1).Text`

Comment: @CarlosE.Ferro and Mr M!  Thank you, both of you now it finally worked!